# How to properly load JSON file in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

Problem: I have a React portfolio project that has a JSON file containing all the image data path for each project, a typical project data look like this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "titleVideo": "https://vimeo.com/...",
    "titleGif": "/images/gif/wall.gif",
    "title": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "table": [...
    ],
    "images": [
        {"id": 1, "src": "/images/projects/project1/.....jpg"},
        {"id": 2, "src": "/images/projects/project1/.....jpg"},
        {"id": 3, "src": "/images/projects/project1/.....jpg"},
        {"id": 4, "src": "/images/projects/project1/.....jpg"},
        {"id": 5, "src": "/images/projects/project1/....jpg"}
    ],

    "video": [
        {"id": 1, "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?..."}
    ]
},
```

So the ideal effect is that I switch to different project pages, and load different project data according to the URL params. I've ALREADY finished this step. To load the JSON data, I used the below code:

In App.js

```
let routes = (
  <Switch onChange={this.routerChange}>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="/project/:name" exact component={ProjectPage}/>
  </Switch>
);
```

Navigation Component

```
<NavLink className = {classes.link} to={"/project/" + title } >{content.name}</NavLink>
```

Use data in project page:

```
import data from '../../store/data.json';

class ProjectPage extends Component {
state = {
    curProj: this.props.match.params.name
}

searchProjectByName = (name, data) => {
    let proj;
    data.forEach(
        project => {
            let short = project.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/, "");
            if (short === name) {
                proj = project;
            }
        }
    )
    return proj;
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.match.params.name !== this.props.match.params.name) {
        this.setState({
            curProj: nextProps.match.params.name,
        })
    }
}

render() {
    let curProj = this.searchProjectByName(this.transformName(this.state.curProj), data);

    DIRECTLY USE proj.images[0]... AS img src DATA
}
```

...

The above solution works functionally, however, when the internet speed is low(on mobile) when switching between project pages, the images, and videos need to wait for an extremely long time to be updated to the new ones, before that, even though the URL is updated, the images are still the showing the previous project images.

I'm thinking of using some sort of function to imitate the async request and to return a Promise and then add some placeholder when loading the page. Is this possible to imitate the async request with local JSON file? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

So the live website is http://rnd.studio/ if anyone is interested. The problem is very obvious on mobile (when you switching between different projects)